# searching whole word in Vim (dash character)

Tags: vim, editor, find, vi

I know for searching a whole word I should use `/\<mypattern\>`. But this is not true for dash (+U002d) character and `/\<-\>` always fails. I also try `/\<\%d45\>` and it fails too. anyone know the reason?

**Edit2:** As @bobbogo mentioned dash is not in 'iskeyword' so I add `:set isk+=-` and `/\<-\>` works!

**Edit1:** I think in Vim `/\<word\>` only is valid for alphanumeric characters and we shouldn't use it for punctuation characters (see Edit2). I should change my question and ask how we can search punctuation character as a whole world for example I want my search found the question mark in "a ? b" and patterns like "??" and "abc?" shouldn't be valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\<` matches the zero-width boundary between a non-word character and a word character. What is a word character? It's specified by the *isk* option (`:help isk`).

Since `-` is not in your *isk* option, then `-` can never *start* a word, thus `\<-` will *never* match.

I don't know what you want, but `/\>-\<` will match the dash in `hello-word`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know the reason of my problem. I want to search for patterns like `-r` not `test-r` nor `-rtest` nor `test-rtest`

Comment: I found it and add it to my question (Edit2)

Comment: I use this mapping to toggle dashes in my keywords: `nnoremap <expr> <leader>t- ':set isk' . (index(split(&isk, ','), '-') == -1 ? '+' : '-') . '=-<cr>:set iskeyword?<cr>'`.

Answer (score 0):

Could always search for the regex `\byourwordhere\b`

Comment: Thanks for reply but I think \b is not in Vim. In vim we should use "\\<" and "\\>"

Answer (score 0):

As OP said. In order to include dash `-` into search just execute:

```
:set isk+=-
```

Thats all.

**Example:** When you press `*` over letter `c` of `color-primary` it will search for entire variable name not just for `color`.